# Actualizar un registro en una tabla Mysql a partir de una variable POST?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

estoy tratando de actualizar un registro en una tabla MySQL, por medio de un script llamado "**prueba_envio_1.php**" el cual selecciona el valor de la primera fila de la tabla con encabezado **turnos en espera** al presionar el boton de **llamar siguiente**, al obtener este dato, lo escribe automáticamente en el **input text** para ser enviado por POST, una vez seleccionado el valor, nuevamente oprimo el boton que ahora se llama **finalizar turno** para finalizar el turno.

```
//  prueba_envio_1.php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Prueba</title> 
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- CUERPO -->
        <center>
        <form name="datos_turnos" method="POST"> 

        <div id="datos_y_turnos_liquidacion">
        <div>  
            <label style="font-size: 35pt; color:yellow" name="estado" id="estado"></label>   <!-- ETIQUETA DE ATENDIENDO : -->
            <label style="font-size: 35pt; color:yellow" name="turn" id="turn"></label><br/>   <!-- ETIQUETA DE TURNO SELECCIONADO -->
            <input type="text" name="turno_oculto" id="turno_oculto" style="text-align: right"> 

        <table id="tabla_turnos" name="tabla_turnos" style="font-size: 18pt; text-align:center" border="1px">  

            <tr>
                <th style="font-size: 18pt">TURNOS EN ESPERA</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>I4</td>     
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>I5</td>     
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>I6</td>     
            </tr>               
        </table>  
        </div>
        </div>  

        <div id="remitir_y_finalizar_liquidacion">
        <div>   
            <button type="button" name="finalizar turno" id="BTN_FINALIZAR_TURNO" class="campana" onclick="cambio_texto('prueba_envio_2.php')" style="width:350px; height:200px; Arial; font-size: 20pt">LLAMAR SIGUIENTE</button>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

<script>
// VARIABLES
var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla_turnos');
var uno = document.getElementById('BTN_FINALIZAR_TURNO');
var estado = document.getElementById('estado');
var turno = document.getElementById('turn');
var oculto = document.getElementById('turno_oculto');

//  PARA CAMBIAR EL TEXTO    CADA VEZ QUE SE DA CLICK EN EL BOTON (SE EJECUTA CADA VEZ QUE DAMOS CLICK AL BOTON DE LLAMAR Y FINALIZAR)
function cambio_texto(destino1) {

//  ESTE IF ES PARA CUANDO PRESIONEMOS EL BOTON EN CASO DE QUERER FINALIZAR TURNO, ES DECIR CUANDO EL BOTON DIGA "FINALIZAR TURNO"  
  if (uno.innerHTML == 'FINALIZAR TURNO'){                      // SI QUIERE FINALIZAR TURNO O LLAMAR
      var respuesta = confirm('¿ ESTA SEGURO QUE DESEA FINALIZAR TURNO ?');
      if(respuesta==true){                                      // SI RESPONDO QUE SI
          uno.innerHTML = 'LLAMAR SIGUIENTE';                   // CAMBIA TEXTO DEL BOTON A "LLAMAR SIGUIENTE"               
          estado.innerText = '';
          turno.innerText = '';
          document.datos_turnos.action = destino1;              // 
          document.datos_turnos.submit();                       // SE ENVIA POR POST A : prueba_envio_2.php
      }
      else{ 

      }
  }

  else{    // ESTE ELSE ES PARA CUNADO PRESIONEMOS EL BOTON EN CASO DE QUERER LLAMAR TURNO, ES DECIR CUANDO EL BOTON DIGA "LLAMAR SIGUIENTE"
    if(tabla.rows[1]){                                           // SI YA SELECCIONO TURNO 
    estado.innerHTML = 'ATENDIENDO: ';
    turno.innerText = tabla.rows[1].textContent;
    oculto.value = tabla.rows[1].textContent;
    uno.innerHTML = 'FINALIZAR TURNO';
    }

    else {                                                       // NO HA SELECCIONADO TURNO
        alert("NO HAY TURNOS EN ESPERA.");
    }
  }  
}
</script>
```

Se supone que al finalizar el turno envia por POST el valor que esta en el **input text** al script **prueba_envio_2.php** el cual se encarga de recibir el dato por POST y actualizar el registro con la hora actual en la fila que corresponda con el dato recibido, pero no sé porque no me realiza la actualización en la base de datos, ya verifiqué si el dato esta llegando imprimiendolo con echo en el script **prueba_envio_2.php** y si esta llegando, pero no realiza la actualizacion.

```
//  prueba_envio_2.php
<?php
include("conexion.php");

date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");

$fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$turno_remitido = $_POST["turno_oculto"];     // SE RECIBE LA VARIABLE POR POST

echo $turno_remitido;            // IMPRIME LA VARIEBLE RECIBIDA POR POST

// ACTUALIZA LA BD DICIENDO

$_UPDATE_SQL = ("UPDATE $tabla1_bd Set 
FINALIZADO = '$fecha_actual'
WHERE TURNO = '$turno_remitido'");        // ACTUALIZAMOS EN LA CELDA QUE COINCIDA CON LA VARIABLE RECIBIDA

mysqli_query($conexion,$_UPDATE_SQL);

header('Location:prueba_envio_1.php');
?>
```

Adjunto el script **conexion.php** y la tabla de la base de datos:

```
//  conexion.php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$usuariobd = "zona1";
$clavebd = "PrimeraZona12345";
$basededatos = "distrito_militar_7";

$tabla1_bd = "ciudadanos";
$tabla2_bd = "login";
$tabla3_bd = "remitidos";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$usuariobd,$clavebd,$basededatos);

if ($conexion->connect_errno){
    echo "Nuestro sistema experimenta fallos...";
    exit();     
}
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe cual es el error, le agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. ¿Revisaste la consulta de actualización que creas en `$_UPDATE_SQL`?  Puedes hacer `echo` de ella y probar la consulta en PHPMyAdmin... ¿Qué tal si el `UPDATE` viola restricciones de duplicidad de datos por ejemplo? ¿Realmente la parte del `WHERE` se está creando bien y existen datos con ese criterio? ¿La conexión funciona?

Comment: Si, he realizado ´echo´ en ´$_UPTADE_SQL´ y me sale esto: "**UPDATE ciudadanos Set FINALIZADO = '2018-10-03 13:27:31' WHERE TURNO = ' I4 '**". Supongo que es correcto porque incluso muestra la hora actual y el valor enviado por POST **I4** al final, pero no lo actualiza en la base de datos...

Comment: ¿Te saca **una tabulación a la izquierda** del valor de la columna `TURNO` y **un espacio en blanco a la derecha**, como aquí: `' I4 '`?  ¿Que arroja un `var_dump($turno_remitido);`?  Debe arrojar `string(2)`, si te arroja `string(4)` significa que el dato no está llegando limpio al servidor, que llega con espacios en blanco, tabulaciones u otros... La consulta final debe quedar así: **`UPDATE ciudadanos Set FINALIZADO = '2018-10-03 13:27:31' WHERE TURNO = 'I4'`**, se parecen, pero no son la misma cosa, tenlo por seguro.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices, me acabo de dar cuenta de los espacios en blanco que está enviando, al realizar el 'var_dump($turno_remitido);' me arroja un **string(15)**  jajaja . Pero entonces la pregunta ahora es, ¿como puedo quitar esos espacios y tabulaciones ? no sé porque sale así, tal vez al momento de adquirir el valor de la fila con javascript ? en el codigo javascript obtengo el valor de la primera fila de la tabla de la siguiente manera: **document.getElementById('turno_oculto').value = tabla.rows[1].textContent;**. Es incorrecto tomarlo de esta forma ? de qué otra forma puedo obtenerlo ?

Comment: En Javascript puedes usar `trim`, por ejemplo: `document.getElementById('turno_oculto').value = tabla.rows[1].textContent.trim();`, aunque deberías revisar de dónde viene el dato que capturas en `tabla.rows[1].textContent` y limpiarlo en su origen, porque ese dato está tomando también tabulaciones y puede tomar otros caracteres extraños difíciles de controlar y que harán que en ciertos casos la condición del `WHERE`  no se cumpla, como ya estamos viendo. Siempre, en vez de implementar soluciones a medio camino, conviene ir a la raíz del problema y limpiar los datos en el origen.

Comment: Gracias capo !! ya funcionó, faltaba añadir **.trim()** al momento de adquirir el valor de la primera fila de la tabla, de esa forma ya adquiere el dato limpio, estaba varado desde ayer por ese detalle...

Comment: Me alegro, escribiré una respuesta de modo que pueda servir a otros usuarios que presenten un problema parecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conviene siempre depurar todo para ver dónde está el problema.

Si dices que tu consulta de actualización se produce así:

```
UPDATE ciudadanos Set FINALIZADO = '2018-10-03 13:27:31' WHERE TURNO = '    I4 '
```

Nada más con copiarla/pegarla en un editor de texto y mostrar los caracteres invisibles, podremos ver que el valor que debería servir de criterio no coincide con los datos reales, porque está viniendo así:  `'   I4 '`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un editor de texto, vemos que:

- a la izquierda del valor hay una tabulación
- a la derecha del valor hay un espacio en blanco

En conclusión, esto: `' I4 '` no es lo mismo que esto: `'I4'`.

Lo puedes comprobar mediante un `var_dump($turno_remitido);` el cual te dirá exactamente cuántos caracteres tiene tu cadena. El valor correcto debería arrojar `string(2)` para el caso de `I4`, si arroja otra cosa es evidente que el criterio del `WHERE` nunca se cumplirá.

Debes por tanto limpiar el dato.

Como dices que lo obtienes así en el cliente:

```
document.getElementById('turno_oculto').value = tabla.rows[1].textContent;
```

Puedes aplicar la función `trim` sobre el valor, de este modo:

```
document.getElementById('turno_oculto').value = tabla.rows[1].textContent.trim();
```

De todos modos, es bueno que controles en su mismo origen el valor que se presenta en `tabla.rows[1].textContent`, estableciendo controles que limpien los datos, por ejemplo, a la hora de insertarlos en bases de datos, en archivos de texto u otros.

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> La forma en que consultas la base de datos es altamente vulnerable a
>   ataques de inyección SQL. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular
>   el valor que se pasa en `$turno_remitido` y provocar graves daños en
>   los datos e incluso en el sistema. Para neutralizar ese tipo de
>   ataques conviene blindar el código mediante el uso de consultas
>   preparadas. Conviene que leas sobre el tema  más adelante.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto a ver:

```
$_UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE {$tabla1_bd} SET FINALIZADO = '{$fecha_actual}' WHERE TURNO = '{$turno_remitido}' ";
```

e intenta con esto para ver los errores

```
die("MySQL error $mysqli_error() <br> Query:<br> $query", $msqli_errno());
```